# Can I stain the side of my cabinet?

Tags: woodworking, staining

Take a look at the attached pictures of my cabinet side. One is cross sectional view and other is side view.

I want to change the color of my cabinet by staining it, but I don't want to hide the wood grain.

By looking at cross sectional view, I don't know if I can sand it down to apply stain, because that top layer doesn't seem like hard wood which I can sand and stain. Am I right? What can I do to change color and still keep the grains visible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a veneer over secondary wood such as poplar...

Comment: I'm not sure which pic you're referring to as a "cross sectional view". A cross section typically involves cutting through the object ("sectioning" it) and showing what it looks like on the inside.

Comment: I think you can sand it very lightly, just to remove the top coat, then apply a darker stain.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be any hidden surface where you could test this.

Comment: @brhans the top pic shows what a cross section through the cabinet would show...

Answer (score 2):

That looks like laminate wood.

Top layer (very thin) looks like veneer over something like poplar.

You should not (can not) sand it off, but remove (sand) the the top coat of polyurethane to allow new stain to penetrate.

Using some darker color stain would cover the old stain.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative technique would be to paint the wood, then seal it with one coat, then apply a gel stain as a glaze.  The glaze would sink into the deep open pores, revealing the same grain pattern.  After allowing the glaze to fully dry, then seal again.

To clarify: This birch plywood was painted with primer and two coats of gray paint, then it was sealed with one coat of poly.  The pores are partly not fully sealed and/or grooves still exists.  I then applied black gel stain as a glaze, which got picked up by these grooves and pores, revealing the original grain pattern.  After several days of drying, I then sealed completely with two additional coats of poly.

[image]

Comment: if you sealed it, how can the glaze seeps in the pores?

Comment: You would be only dealing with one coat. I used this method on a island back and it was tremendous. Gray paint. One coat sealer. Then glaze. It allowed the glaze to only grab hold of the STILL open pores.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this method.  The current cabinet is already sealed. Then you seal further with paint, and then again with one coat. How can pores still be open?  Furthermore, gel stain is not a penetrating stain. How can you see the grain?  You can see the grain even on bare wood let alone a finished cabinet that you put another coat of paint.

Comment: I can elaborate and post a photo.

Comment: Oak also has DEEP pores.  In the past, I had to use many coats of poly to seal them fully.  I don't think the glaze would have any problem gathering in those oak grain grooves.

Comment: Great thanks. I have oak kitchen cabinet finished with poly.  I am looking for the easiest way to change it's appearance.  Sanding down everything is gonna be a too much work and dust in the house.

Comment: That oak grain is almost impossible to fill completely. Some woodworkers even resort to a plaster mixture. You should buy a small piece and experiment.

Comment: I have used oak for my stair threads and 3 coats of polyurethane did seal it completely.  I can understand your point w/ penetrating sealers, but topical sealers easily seal everything often with just one coat.

Comment: It also depends on what direction the wood is cut. Bottom line is painting methods like this require time for experiments.